# LibGDX Loading Screen Not Working

Tags: java, libgdx

I have this piece of code for a loading screen on my LibGDX game in java:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends AbstractScreen {

    private Stage stage;

    private Image logo;
    private Image loadingFrame;
    private Image loadingBarHidden;
    private Image screenBg;
    private Image loadingBg;

    private float startX, endX;
    private float percent;

    private Actor loadingBar;

    public LoadingScreen(BloodyMess game) {
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("3");

        Constants c = new Constants();
        // Tell the manager to load assets for the loading screen
        game.manager.load("data/loading.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
        // Wait until they are finished loading
        game.manager.finishLoading();

        // Initialize the stage where we will place everything
        stage = new Stage();

        // Get our textureatlas from the manager
        TextureAtlas atlas = game.manager.get("data/loading.pack", TextureAtlas.class);

        // Grab the regions from the atlas and create some images
        logo = new Image(atlas.findRegion("libgdx-logo"));
        loadingFrame = new Image(atlas.findRegion("loading-frame"));
        loadingBarHidden = new Image(atlas.findRegion("loading-bar-hidden"));
        screenBg = new Image(atlas.findRegion("screen-bg"));
        loadingBg = new Image(atlas.findRegion("loading-frame-bg"));

        // Add the loading bar animation
        Animation anim = new Animation(0.05f, atlas.findRegions("loading-bar-anim"));
        anim.setPlayMode(PlayMode.LOOP_REVERSED);
        loadingBar = new LoadingBar(anim);

        // Or if you only need a static bar, you can do
        // loadingBar = new Image(atlas.findRegion("loading-bar1"));

        // Add all the actors to the stage
        stage.addActor(screenBg);
        stage.addActor(loadingBar);
        stage.addActor(loadingBg);
        stage.addActor(loadingBarHidden);
        stage.addActor(loadingFrame);
        stage.addActor(logo);

        // Add everything to be loaded
        System.out.println("6");
        c.guy_1_face = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("guy_1_face.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // Set our screen to always be XXX x 480 in size
        width = 480 * width / height;
        height = 480;
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);

        // Make the background fill the screen
        screenBg.setSize(width, height);

        // Place the logo in the middle of the screen and 100 px up
        logo.setX((width - logo.getWidth()) / 2);
        logo.setY((height - logo.getHeight()) / 2 + 100);

        // Place the loading frame in the middle of the screen
        loadingFrame.setX((stage.getWidth() - loadingFrame.getWidth()) / 2);
        loadingFrame.setY((stage.getHeight() - loadingFrame.getHeight()) / 2);

        // Place the loading bar at the same spot as the frame, adjusted a few
        // px
        loadingBar.setX(loadingFrame.getX() + 15);
        loadingBar.setY(loadingFrame.getY() + 5);

        // Place the image that will hide the bar on top of the bar, adjusted a
        // few px
        loadingBarHidden.setX(loadingBar.getX() + 35);
        loadingBarHidden.setY(loadingBar.getY() - 3);
        // The start position and how far to move the hidden loading bar
        startX = loadingBarHidden.getX();
        endX = 440;

        // The rest of the hidden bar
        loadingBg.setSize(450, 50);
        loadingBg.setX(loadingBarHidden.getX() + 30);
        loadingBg.setY(loadingBarHidden.getY() + 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // Clear the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        System.out.println("5");
        if (game.manager.update()) { // Load some, will return true if done
                                        // loading
            System.out.println("4");
            game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));

        }

        // Interpolate the percentage to make it more smooth
        percent = Interpolation.linear.apply(percent, game.manager.getProgress(), 0.1f);

        // Update positions (and size) to match the percentage
        loadingBarHidden.setX(startX + endX * percent);
        loadingBg.setX(loadingBarHidden.getX() + 30);
        loadingBg.setWidth(450 - 450 * percent);
        loadingBg.invalidate();

        System.out.println("2");

        // Show the loading screen
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // Dispose the loading assets as we no longer need them
        game.manager.unload("data/loading.pack");
    }
}
```

The problem is that it isn't running the MainMenu screen and as you can see I have some debugging code with numbers in the console, and it only outputs 3 and then 6, but nothing else. Can anybody tell me why it isn't loading my main menu screen or running anything else in the code? FYI I didn't write a lot of this, I got it from here: https://github.com/Matsemann/libgdx-loading-screen/tree/libgdx-1.4.1-Deathsbreed

EDIT: I have all of my values in a file called Constants, and everything loads from there. If you need any more info, I will edit the OP.

Much Appreciated,

Luke

Comment: Also I'm SUPER new to LibGDX so really wanting that constructive criticism.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not setting the active screen to be your loading screen.  '3' and '6' are only printed in your loading screen constructor. I can't tell without seeing the entry point for your game.  Its probably wherever LoadingScreen you're creating an instance of LoadingScreen.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison i have this: `game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));`

Comment: Right, but you need to set loading screen as the main screen somewhere else, so that your loading screen's `render` method can be called by LIBGDX's Game class.  Somewhere you've got code setting the loading screen as your game's screen right? Something like `setScreen(new LoadingScreen(game));`

Comment: @WilliamMorrison yes, `public class BloodyMess extends Game {

 public AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

 @Override
 public void create() {
  setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this));
 }

 @Override
 public void render() {
 }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the comments, you have in the `BloodyMess`

```
@Override 
public void render() { }
```

Inside render method put

```
super.render();
```

And this will start working as your need to call super class's render method in order to process render methods of your abstract screens.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks!! I'm really new to this haha